# Django: Problems related Many-to-many relationships

Tags: python, django, model, many-to-many

code of models.py

```
from django.db import models

class a(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class b(models.Model):
    roll=models.IntegerField()
    a=models.ManyToManyField(a)
```

Actually i'm learning Django.As i have defined a **many-to-many** relationship in *b* model with *a* model.I'm trying to do some experiment with these models so that i can get better understanding of **many-to-many** relationship.

doing some experiments with my models in Django shell.

```
In [1]: from payment.models import a,b

In [2]: x=a(name="test")

In [3]: x.save()

In [4]: y=b(roll=4)

In [5]: y.save()

In [6]: y.a.add(x)

In [13]: x=b.objects.filter(a__id=4)

In [14]: x[0].a
Out[14]: <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager at 0x6a833a60f0>

In [15]: x[0].a.name

In [16]:
```

When i run x[0].a.name in shell it does not return anything why?Do we cannot access name attribute like this.How to know which objects of *a* model are in relation with **y object** of **b** model.

Comment: `x[0].a` is a collection of elements, not a single one. You thus can fetch the related objects with `x[0].a.all()`, and for example obtain the name of the first one with `x[0].a.all()[0].name`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you it's worked.One more question can i delete **a** model objects which are in relation with y object of **b** model through django-admin.when i try to do it through django-admin '-' sign not showing to delete, only '+' showing to add more objects of **a** model.